# Wordpress is using index.php instead of single.php for posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a Worpdress Theme and want to show my posts. I created single.php but when I open the post it displays it in index.php. Since single.php is higher in the hirarchy than index.php this should not happen.

For single.php I tried a very simple version like

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
Showing single.php
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and to be sure to have no erros I also tried to copy the single.php from twentytwelve. With both versions I have the same problem.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Disable all plugins and then try again.

Comment: There are no plugins enabled.

Comment: Start debugging WP then. Follow its internal include chain and track where it breaks. This should not happen! See this https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Are you sure it is not a page instead of a post?

Comment: Do the file has the permissions to be seen by php?

Comment: Is the active theme the theme you are modifying?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: I cleared the cache and tried differente browsers.

Comment: Try resetting the permalinks

Comment: @dwhite: Tried that, too.

Comment: Is a fresh install of WP an option?

Comment: It is a new install. It is a really simple Theme that I am creating. For the single.php I need the header.php and footer.php. Maybe there is something missing? Header and footer have the normal html, head, body, ... and <?php wp_head(); ?> / <?php wp_footer(); ?>

Comment: Anything like template_redirect or pre_get_posts filters in your functions.php ? Can you post the contents of the file ?

Comment: My theme does not have a functions.php. I understand that this file is optional.

Comment: @JohannesN You have a style.css? Not loading `index.php` from the default/an other theme? :)

Comment: No, I deleted all other themes that were in the themes folder to be sure.

Comment: Setup a new WP folder, a new Vhost or Site in your Web Server, download WP, setup the theme again and see how it works out. What you describe here is impossible hence cannot be solved remotely.

Comment: Is the file name lower case? single.php, not Single.php?

Comment: How do you know that its using `index.php` instead of `single.php`. Is your theme is child or parent?

Comment: @RahilWazir: I just wrote "This is single.php" in the single.php file. In index.php I wrote "This is index". Then I created a post and it says "This is index" when I preview it. My theme is parent.

Comment: @CodeAngry: I had it running on my local server. I set it all up with a new isntallation on the server now -> problem continues

Comment: @JohannesN could you upload theme.zip file to let us check it.

Comment: Do you have a template_redirect within your template?

Comment: @enapupe Does that make any difference? I am facing the same issue. My posts were previously using single.php but after updating the posts, it started using index.php template.

Comment: @Debs Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I know this sounds funny, but resave your permalinks in your Wordpress dashboard. If that doesn't work, I would try deleting and recreating single.php.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's crazy but from my experience What helped me was a simple change back to Standard Permalinks in "Settings" -> "Permalinks" and a restore back to "Name of the Post" (Beitragsname)....

...maybe this might help someone else as well...